# Audio files not found after deployed to Heroku through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, heroku

My web contains some audio files in wav format. I have no problem in loading these wav files in local by running "foreman start". However, after I deploy to heroku, it says that all these audios files are not found. Actually, when I take a look at the sources, I do not see my audio files. I am using node.js. Do I need to do something in the package.json. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not store static assets like images, audio files, etc...

Use a third party service such as Amazon S3 to store your audio files.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3